# Making network from line feature class using Network Analyst in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, template

So I have points in an area and want to find the shortest distance to travel to all the points once by plane. So I think I need to do a network analysis. I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a line feature class that connects every point to all other points (removing duplicates and connections to itself, etc.). I know this isn't a true road network but I am hoping it is possible to "hack it" into acting similar since the flight lines connect to each point and represent the potential travel routes.

I have been following this tutorial and made a network no problem with their sample data: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/transportation/create-a-local-government-network-dataset/

It goes through how to make a network from a feature class BUT the issue is it already comes with a template to use that only works with the specific sample data that comes with the tutorial.

I can't figure out how to make a network from the feature class I made without a template. I have the attributes needed, it's in a feature dataset, has a projected coordinate system, a "street name", all that sort of stuff.

Does anyone have any idea how to made a network dataset without a template?